# Using javascript function parameters to affect different variables

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to make small application which uses some html checkbox form objects. Whenever any of those checkboxes are checked on or off, it runs a function which then changes the value of a variable unique to each checkbox. How would I go about making it so that using the arguments of the function - or some other means - I'm able to target the corresponding variable for whenever one of the checkboxes is clicked? Currently here's what I'm attempting to accomplish.

HTML:

```
 <form action="" method="get" name="orderForm">
<input name="Test" type="checkbox" value="test" onchange="checkClick('1','5.00')" />Test 1<br />
<input name="Test" type="checkbox" value="test2" onchange="checkBoxClick('2','3.00')" />Test 2 <br />
<input name="Test" type="checkbox" value="test3" onchange="checkBoxClick('3','4.00')" />Test 3 <br />
```

And the Javascript:

```
//set global vars
var check1 = 0.00;
var check2 = 0.00;
var check3 = 0.00;

function checkClick(num,cost) {
    if (check+num == 0.00) {
        check+num = cost;
    }
    else {
        check+num = 0.00;
    }
    checkBoxClick();
}

function checkBoxClick() {
    document.getElementById("otherContainer").innerHTML = "<p>" + check1 + "<br />" + check2 + "<br />" + check3 + "<br />" + check4 + "</p>";
}
```

At the moment it's just a crude test, but what I'm trying to do is make it so I only need one function that will handle each of the different checkboxes and their variables without having to make a different function for each one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see what you're trying to do. Make a variable `check` an array instead:

```
var check = [ 0.00, 0.00, 0.00 ];
```

Also, pass your parameters as numbers instead:

```
checkClick(1, 5.00)
```

But since arrays are 0-indexed, start with 0 instead of 1:

```
checkClick(0, 5.00)
```

And where ever you did `check+num` replace it with `check[num]`.

Here is the result:

```
var check = [ 0.00, 0.00, 0.00 ];

function checkClick(num, cost) {
    if (check[num] == 0.00) {
        check[num] = cost;
    } else {
        check[num] = 0.00;
    }
    checkBoxClick();
}

function checkBoxClick() {
    document.getElementById("otherContainer").innerHTML = "<p>" + check[1] + "<br />" + check[2] + "<br />" + check[3] + "<br />" + check[4] + "</p>";
}
```

*BTW, you're using `check4` when you never made a `check4` variable...*

Comment: Ahh beautiful! Making it an array instead completely slipped my mind, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

En HTML:

```
<input name="Test" type="checkbox" value="test" onchange="checkClick(this,'5.00')" />Test 1<br />
<input name="Test" type="checkbox" value="test2" onchange="checkClick(this,'3.00')" />Test 2 <br />
<input name="Test" type="checkbox" value="test3" onchange="checkClick(this,'4.00')" />Test 3 <br />
```

En Javascript:

```
function checkClick(element,cost) {
   switch (element.value) {
      case 'test':
         check1 = (element.checked) ? cost : 0;  
         break;
      case 'test2':
         check2 = (element.checked) ? cost : 0;  
         break;
      case 'test3':
         check3 = (element.checked) ? cost : 0;
         break;
      }
      checkBoxClick();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array instead of three separate variables. Then modify the array element based on the number you are passing to the function.

Better still, try using java objects with keys as the id of the checkbox.